# php assign separated variables to a variable that contain many values

Tags: php, email

I have this loop, which puts email addresses inside a `$sendmail` variable.

```
<?php  do { ?>    
<?php
$sendmail .= $row_Recordset2['companyemail'].","." ";
?>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset2 =mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2)); ?>
```

and if I print the variable:
`<?php echo $sendmail; ?>`

returns some email addresses like:
email1@email.com, email2@email.com, email3@email.com,

how can i put this emails inside variables, for example:

`$email1@email.com`
`$email2@email.com`
`$email3@email.com`

Comment: You can't and you shouldn't. Arrays were invented for that. Look that word up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this with arrays as suggested by @N.B.:

```
<?php  do { ?>    
<?php
$sendmail[] = $row_Recordset2['companyemail'];
?>
<?php } while ($row_Recordset2 =mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2)); ?>
```

to print it out:

```
print_r($sendmail);
```

to access individual emails:

```
echo $sendmail[0];
echo $sendmail[1];
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php  
while ($row_Recordset2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($Recordset2)) {
 $sendmail = $row_Recordset2['companyemail'];
 echo $sendmail;
}
?>
```